High CPU load from lsphp - Cpanel
I am using AlmaLinux 8.9 with cPanel and LiteSpeed installed. I have a WordPress site on this server, which, according to Google Analytics, usually has no more than 2-4 visitors at any given time. However, today the server load has skyrocketed. Despite having a 4-core processor, the server load has gone up to 37 cores, and I can't figure out why the server is under such pressure.
I am also using CSF on the server, but I'm not sure if the issue is due to internal web server problems, issues with the site's PHP code, or an external attack. The site’s code hasn’t changed recently, and no new plugins have been installed. All plugins are official and disabling them doesn’t resolve the issue. The only thing that temporarily reduces the server load is changing the database password in the wp-config.php file.
Please help me diagnose and resolve this problem.


What is in the log files?  Does the access log show lots of hits all of a sudden?

Your MySQL server looks to be under a lot of load - which is why your CPU usage is so high.   if you are being attacked (and my guess is you are), this may not show up in Google Analytics because the attackers won't be hitting the javascript.  Look at your log files.    You may also want to tune your database - and/or check the integrity of the underlying files.   If you don't have a cache that might help.

(this should be a comment, but space limited in the comments box)

Please help me diagnose and resolve this problem.

I once tried to document the process for diagnosing and resolving performance issues on LAMP - I stopped at around 400 pages. And that was without even looking at Wordpress. If it helps, you can read the process/suggestions.

The only thing that temporarily reduces the server load is changing the database password in the wp-config.php file.

That's very unusual. How does this impact the mysqld CPU usage? Whats the impact on load? What's happenning to the free memory & swap when you do this?
